# JQuery UI: Can I use Theme Roller to make a Custom Theme That Matches My PSD Mockup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Photoshop mockup that has some customized buttons and inputs and I would like to use JQuery UIs theme roller to accomplish this. However my mockup includes some things that the theme roller does not allow me to customize, (like certain drop shadows gradient overlays and inner shadows to name a few). Also I would like to use different background textures for the progress bar than for the other UI widgets. The options I have that I can think of are:

1. don't use JQuery UI, (kinda lame option though)
2. download a custom UI and use custom CSS styling and edit the images with Photoshop.

Those options however (if they even work) seem a bit cumbersome. Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the themes on http://jqueryui.com/themeroller
If that's not enough, the docs describe the css structure used, so you can modify it manually http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/CustomThemes